# .NET Code access security

Tags: c#, .net, security

Consider the following scenario. An application is created to manage personnel records for which each employee record is stored in a separate single file. Read and write access must be controlled independently for different types of employee data. The tool must be authorized to read and write some sections (such as contact information), to only read other sections (such as historical information) and must not have any access to other sensitive sections (such as pay rate).

How might access be properly controlled using CAS? Will the built-in CAS functionality be sufficient in this scenario?

My thinking is as follows:

We can segregate code according to the type of operation such as one for contact information, the other for historical information etc. Then assign each of them in separate application domains (with the appropriate security permissions to the domain). Can we explicitly specify creation of application domains and the associated permissions in C#?

Comment: Gigantic overkill (IMO).. why not just maintain this security in your code?

Comment: When you say "file" do you mean flat file?  Or are you using a database of some kind?

Comment: Would you be able to break the sensitive information to separate files than the non sensitive information? Also is flat file a hard requirement? a database would be a much more logical way to store this kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would focus on guarding the data.

Put the flat files in directories which have the appropriate permissions (e.g. define which groups should have access, grant access to the group, and maintain the ACL for each group to correspond to the users).

When your app tries to open one of the files, you have to handle two cases:

1. The file opens.  Handle this case per normal and display the UI.
2. The file access is denied due to inadequate filesystem permission.  Your app should display an appropriate error at this point and then allow the user to go back to the main menu or whatever.

Don't think you need to do anything beyond this.  Code access permissions are for guarding code logic, not guarding data.

Comment: I think the problem is he is wanting to restrict from reading sections from *within* the file. This would be perfect if the sensitive info is inside the same file as the non sensitive info, but not if it is combined.

Comment: Yikes, that sure makes it difficult!